# Add CSS class to django RadioSelect label

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-forms

So I have a few widgets setup like this

```
widgets = {
        'history': Select(attrs={'ng-model': 'data.smile_assessment.history'}),
        'concern': Select(attrs={'ng-model': 'data.smile_assessment.concern'}),
        'crowding': RadioSelect(attrs={'ng-model': 'data.smile_assessment.crowding'}),
        'spacing': RadioSelect(attrs={'ng-model': 'data.smile_assessment.spacing'}),
        'age_group': Select(attrs={'ng-model': 'data.smile_assessment.age_group'}),
        'gender': Select(attrs={'ng-model': 'data.smile_assessment.gender'}),
    }
```

And rendered like this

```
<li>{{ form.history }}</li>
<li>{{ form.concern }}</li>
<li>{{ form.crowding }}</li>
<li>{{ form.spacing }}</li>
<li>What is your age group: {{ form.age_group }}</li>
<li>What is your gender: {{ form.gender }}</li>
```

What I want to do is apply a the same css class to the label of the two RadioSelect forms.
Currently the label looks like this

```
<label for="id_2"></label>
```

And I want it to look like this

```
<label class="myclass" for="id_2"></label>
```

Not really sure how to go about this, I can modify the attrs of the RadioSelect widget but that only lets me set the class of the input tag, not the label tag.

Answer (score 0):

for those who will be looking at this question i found a trick..... i Don't know what's up with the RadioSelect() widget.... i rendered my template like this:

```
{% for choice in form.category_res %}
        <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
            {{ choice.tag }}
            <label for="{{ choice.id_for_label  }}" class="custom-control-label">{{ choice.choice_label }}</label>
        </div>
{% endfor %}
```

(category_res) is my field with choices 
I am know using django2.0 with python3.6 and i used bootstrap4.0 on my template... I hope this works for you